# Docker-Compose mounted files are not owned by root

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I'm mounting files from my laptop's/host machine's working directory into the container, and I'm not sure why the mounted files are owned by `www-data`. `q` was created on the host machine, so it's owned by `root`, as expected.

**Inside container:**

[image]

**Some other observations:**

Host UID (my OS X account): 1783256022 (not sure why it looks like this)

Container UID (www-data): 33

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:1.13.8

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nano && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y procps && \
    apt-get install net-tools

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    image: tc-web:0.1.0
    container_name: tc-web
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
      - ./docker/nginx/.bashrc:/root/.bashrc
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Comment: Are you on a Linux host?

Comment: I’m using OS X.

Answer (score 2):

When you mount a directory using volumes in a Unix like system, files will keep the same permissions they have in the host in terms of uid a gid. That means that the uid that created the files in your host (your user probably) has the same user id of the www-data user inside the container.

When you create a file from inside the container, since the container is run as the root user, files will be owned by the root user (inside and outside the Container).

Comment: That's good to know. I did check out the UIDs, and they don't appear to the same, however. I updated the post with the actual IDs. Could you take a look? Under Some other observations.

Comment: Also, I tried creating new files on the host and chown to other users. These new files appear as owned by `root` as well.

Comment: Don't know docker on Mac os X works at the moment. Do you have a virtual machine or is it all running on the host?

Comment: I'm running this on the host directly using the OSX client.

Comment: So what does `ls -ln` return in your host on the directory you are using as volume?

Comment: they appeared as owned by my OS X account properly. There was some weird ownerhip mapping going on. Couldn't figure it out, so I remade the entire image, and it didn't happen again.